# Advice: USB Monitoring Programming

Tags: linux, usb, unix

I need an advice about USB programming in linux. i have to design a USB monitoring program that 'll keep checking usb ports of a linux cent os. as soon as a usb or external hard disk is connected, this program will shoot an email to some specific person about detail of usb (as size, mount on, time). when usb is disconnected, it will again shoot an email to some person with same kind of information. mean while this program will also write logs in syslog/messages with name of programing for easy tracking.

Now I want ask that what is best way to develop this program. as I'm new to this field so i know nothing about it? either i should use perl, bash scripting or some other language? I have no idea what is right way to adopt coz this program will keep running all the time to keep a check on usb ports. I know few commands in like lsusb, fdisk (to check attached usb) and df -h (to get detail of usb) but dont know how i can achieve using these commands that i am thinking.

also one more thing that in future i also need to modify this program for ubuntu and    Citrix XenServer and it should be same everywhere.

Comment: Read the hotplug documentation.

Comment: if your organization doesn't want people copying files to a USB drive, maybe they should just set up security to USB ports for read-only access. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can develop a script in Perl to do that, take a look at the [Device::USB](http://search.cpan.org/~gwadej/Device-USB-0.35/USB.pm) module, should help ...

Comment: thanks for your input. just confirm me that perl program is better way than bash programming? coz I have no idea either about bash/perl/any other language. so i want to know which will be better for a starter in above mentioned case.

Comment: The better depends on what you have to do ... The context determine the better ...

Answer (score 0):

dmesg already logs this in the system log. If you are monitoring the system log already somehow(example syslog-ng), you can create an alert to send you an email whenever dmesg detects an usb change. Or you can write a simple bash script to monitor the system log file.

For a starter, I think bash would be easier(obviously perl would be more powerful). Not sure if Citrix Xenserver logs dmesg or not.